# time.Since() giving 0s

Tags: go

I'm having a problem where time.Since() is producing 0s. Can anyone explain out of the blue why this may happen? I'm trying to measure the execution time of a webserver call.

```
func handle(f http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println(r.URL.Path)
        start := time.Now()
        f(w, r)
        elapsed := time.Since(start)
        log.Printf("took %s", elapsed)
    }
}
```

It produces this output, where it sometimes gives **"took 0s"**. Am I missing something here?

```
2019/01/24 23:28:45 /hello
2019/01/24 23:28:45 took 1.9878ms
2019/01/24 23:28:45 /hello
2019/01/24 23:28:45 took 998.6µs
2019/01/24 23:28:46 /hello
2019/01/24 23:28:46 took 1.0007ms
2019/01/24 23:28:46 /hello
2019/01/24 23:28:46 took 0s
2019/01/24 23:28:46 /hello
2019/01/24 23:28:46 took 0s
2019/01/24 23:28:46 /hello
2019/01/24 23:28:46 took 998.8µs
2019/01/24 23:28:47 /hello
2019/01/24 23:28:47 took 0s
2019/01/24 23:28:47 /hello
2019/01/24 23:28:47 took 0s
```

Comment: Are you using windows? The time taken was simply below the timer resolution on your platform.

Comment: It depends on the OS you are using. IIRC Linux's time resolution for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` should be 1µs, Windows' default timer is 15.6ms (can be lower but requires a dive into manual syscalls not in the stdlib), and macOS should also be 1µs.

Comment: Correct, windows.

Answer (score 4):

I replicated your scenario with a simple function that takes microseconds(µs) to execute.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        start := time.Now()

        var i = rand.Float64() * 100

        time.Sleep(time.Duration(i) * time.Microsecond)

        elapsed := time.Since(start)
        fmt.Printf("took %s", elapsed)
        fmt.Println()

    }

}
```

But I did not get 0s

Output:

```
Start
took 60µs
took 94µs
took 66µs
took 43µs
took 42µs
took 68µs
took 6µs
took 15µs
took 9µs
took 30µs
```

Comment: Thank you Gopher for reproducing! Can you mention the platform and OS where you have run it?
Also, OP's handler seems to only print "/hello". I'm not sure that `time.Sleep` is equivalent here, as it might trigger some context switching in the scheduler.